# SQL Server and C# Master / Detail Insert

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, master-detail

I am creating stored procedures that will be called from my C# application and will enter master/detail information into SQL Server. On the Header table I have `TransactionId` as an Identity column so that I get a unique ID every time I insert. When I call my stored procedure for the detail table, I would like to use the PK ID from the Header and insert it into the FK of the detail. What is the best way to ensure that I get back the ID that was just created in the Header table?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Header835]
(
   [TRANSACTIONID] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
   , [FILENAME] [varchar](80) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
   , [TRADINGPARTNERNAME] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
   , [ISACRTL] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL
   , [STCRTL] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL
   , CONSTRAINT [PK_Header835] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
   (
      [TRANSACTIONID] ASC
   ) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: I have tried getting the Max ID from the table ( SET @TEMPTRANXID = (SELECT  MAX(H.TRANSACTIONID) FROM  [DB].[dbo].[HeaderTable] H)) But I am thinking this may not always work if multiple calls are made to the table by different instance of the application.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Header835](
 [TRANSACTIONID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [FILENAME] [varchar](80) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
 [TRADINGPARTNERNAME] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
 [ISACRTL] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
 [STCRTL] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Header835] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [TRANSACTIONID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: Are you allowing the user to use the same file name more than once? That could get ugly if you need to audit it later.

Comment: Yes but I am thinking of adding a time stamp to the file name each time it is processed. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know the application you're working on right now, but I don't think allowing users to upload the same file is a good idea, even with a timestamp. For my application I save the file to the server when they upload it, throwing an error if it's already there so that come auditing time we can look back and see everything that got sent in to the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll wan to use [**SCOPE_IDENTITY()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

```
DECLARE @headerTransactionId INT;

INSERT INTO dbo.Header835(Filename, TradingPartnerName, IsACrtl, StCrtl)
SELECT 'myFile.txt', 'Joe', 103, 123;

SELECT @headerTransactionId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3028/3/0) Example

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for introducing me to sql fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my blog post about different methods and there advantages and disadvantages here:

http://sqlity.net/en/351/identity-crisis/

In short, you want your code to look like this:

```
DECLARE @IdentValues TABLE(v INT);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Header835](<...  column list ...>) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.[TRANSACTIONID] INTO @IdentValues(v)
VALUES(<... value list ...>);

SELECT v AS IdentityValues FROM @IdentValues;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It will be useful to me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have inserted a record in your Header835 table, you get the auto generated identity value of TransactionId with SELECT @@IDENTITY or SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(), both will return you the last auto generated identity in the session.
You  can then use this value in the foreign key of detail records.