# How to add data in both of table header and detail in SQL visual studio c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datagridview, datatable

I want save data in 2 table with different data.

table master: KD001 (PK), name

example in table PurchaseReuqisition contain: PR001(PK), KD001 (FK), date

table DetailPurchaseRequisition contain: PR001 as (PK, FK), KD001 as (PK, FK), qty

when I click add table DetailPurchaseRequisition can contain duplicate id, example:
PR001, KD002

PR001, KD004

this is my code:

```
public void cekdup2()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; col++)
            {
                if (dataGridView2.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value != null &&
                  dataGridView2.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.Equals(txtIdBarang.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("cant add same item!");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and button add:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cekdup2();


        if (txtIdBarang.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("choose item!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else if (numQty.Value == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Qty min 1!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
          con.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO DetailPurchaseRequisition VALUES('" + txtIdPermintaanPembelian.Text + "','" + txtIdBarang.Text + "', '" + numQty.Value + "')");
          dataGridView2.DataSource = con.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DetailPurchaseRequisition");
         }
        }
```

but when I click add, theree's something error,
if I fill PR004, it can be error because in table PurchaseRequisition not found,
but if I save both of them like this example:

```
 con.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO DetailPurchaseRequisition VALUES('" + IdPR.Text + "','" + txtIdBarang.Text + "', '" + numQty.Value + "')");
        con.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO PruchaseRequisition VALUES('" + IdPR.Text + "','" + txtIdBarang.Text + "', '" + numQty.Value + "')");
```

it will be looping save for table PurchaseRequisition right?
I just want save 1time for table PurchaseRequisition, but can save more than 1data in table Detail..

can u help me pls?
*sorry for my bad english

Comment: PLEASE! Try capitalizing your "i"s. If you say sorry for bad English, why not capitalize your "i"s to relieve us some burden?

Comment: Dear @CrazyPython: by all means, do suggest an edit, instead of just writing a comment complaining about correct capitalization. If you believe you can make this question better, why don't you?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Why did you make that comment instead of editing it? See, apply your own logic to yourself.

Comment: @crazyPython: I did not edit the question since I don't think I can improve it much; the grammer mistakes is not what makes this question unclear. I actually did start editting it but then realized It useless since I'm not even sure I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to design a system to identify new or existing master table entries. The steps will be something like this: Does the primary key exist in the master table? If not insert it. Then insert the detail record.

It **may** be possible to hold a copy of the whole master table in C# memory and do the logic in the client, but that could be risky if the table is big. I would suggest a stored procedure to do everything in the database. Your requirement is very simple - you know the master record primary key beforehand, so you don't need to get it after an INSERT; and you are only adding one detail record at a time.

See for example these links:

[SQL Server and C# Master / Detail Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058109/sql-server-and-c-sharp-master-detail-insert)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/2e35e85f-b69c-4041-9548-6db75c2783e2/inserting-data-in-to-master-and-detail-table

Answer (score 1):

A couple of comments to help you figure out what is going wrong.  Do not execute insert statement by position. This will make debugging these type of issues easier and prevent data from being inserted into the wrong columns.
Insert Into  DetailPurchaseRequisition  (PR001, KD001, qty) Values ('" + IdPR.Text + "','" + txtIdBarang.Text + "', '" + numQty.Value + "')");

From what I can figure out, it appears that you have already done the save of the PurchaseRequisition and you want to save the child records.  It appears you are getting an error due to the parent record not existing in the database.

You need to ensure that after the save of the PurchaseRequsition that you are refreshing the object in memory. Once that id exist in memory, you can then reference it and populate it tn the subsequent insert statement.